# How can I make a function read a database, grab ~10 posts (4 columns to each post) and return all the data?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach, mysqli

I am trying to write a function in php to read posts information (title, content, author, published) from a mysql database using mysqli functions. I'm fairly new to everything, including mysqli but I have taken my best shot and at the moment have this:

```
foreach(readPosts($pageid) as $posts)
        echo $posts;
```

which is just showing the first post. The function is below

```
function readPosts($pageid) {
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    return false;
}
$pageid = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$pageid);
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE pageID = '$pageid'")) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $time1 = date('H:i \o\n jS M Y', $row['publishedtime']);
        $postarray[$i++] = $row['title'];
        $postarray[$i++] = $row['content'];
        $postarray[$i++] = $row['author'];
        $postarray[$i++] = $time1;
    }
    $result->close();
}
mysqli_close($mysqli);
return $postarray;
```

}

So my question is, how do I make it give me all the information, not just one posts info.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use $result->fetch_all()  See the docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)

Answer (score 0):

In the foreach loop you every readPost() calls make a new mysql connection which closed before return.
You should have to make a connection before foreach, iterate over the selected data as in array, and may close connection after the last loop.